# cvResizeWindow() flicker reaction

Tags: opencv

I have an OpenCV window that I would like to resize to fill my screen, but when I use the resize function the window flickers. The output is my webcam and I guess the flicker is because my camera does not have those dimensions. Is there any other way to make the output from the camera larger?

```
cvNamedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

IplImage *frame=0;
frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);

cvShowImage("video", frame);

cvResizeWindow("video", 1920,1080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you an example of using [cvResize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#void%20cvResize%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20int%20interpolation%29) to resize the image or frame.

```
IplImage *frame;
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
cvNamedWindow("capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    IplImage *frame_resize = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1366, 768), frame -> depth, frame -> nChannels);
    cvResize(frame, frame_resize, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    cvShowImage("capture", frame);
    cvWaitKey(25);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the [cvResize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#void%20cvResize%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20int%20interpolation%29) function to change the size of the frame.
However, an easier way is to get rid of the `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` flag  -- without that the video will be displayed at the size of the window.

Something like this:

```
cvNamedWindow("video", 0);
cvResizeWindow("video", 1920,1080);

IplImage *frame=0;
while(true)
{
    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);

    cvShowImage("video", frame);
    int c = waitKey(10);
    ...
}
```

I am not sure of the cause of the flickering, as I could not replicate that issue on my system.
Therefore I cannot guarantee that the flickering will disappear for you (but at least the video should be the correct size).

Comment: Thanks, the flickering is gone. This makes the window bigger but the video output is still the same size.

Comment: Can you post your code? OpenCV (2.4.5, windows 7) resizes the video to the window for me, without explicitly calling cvResize(). What version are you using?